# Passing variables using PHP/PDO

Tags: variables, mysqli, pdo, parameter-passing

Not sure if I described my problem correctly in the title but...

I'd like to get help with the following.  I have been working on this for longer than I care to mention.  I am converting a website from MySql to PDO.
I have a page now that contains several "messages"(videos) that when the "View" button is pressed it opens a new page and is supposed to play the selected video.

All is working fine except the problem I have is, is that when the new page is opened I am not getting the correct file to load.  It is loading the very last file in my database.  The URL indicates that the correct "id" number is passed to the new page, i.e. /webpage.php?id=1, 2 3, etc etc.

It has taken me quite a while to get the page to open and to actually have  a video load that is playable.  I have tried many, many different options I have seen here and other sites but I am missing something.  That something is probably a simple solution. (I admit I only maintain this one site for my step-son and it is running fine with mysql but I know I need to update it and based on what I have read I should go with PDO).

On the page that you would choose which video you want to view I have:

```
    public function dataview($query)
 {
     $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
     $stmt->execute();

     if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
     {
            while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
               ?>
               <tr>
               <td><button onClick="popUpVid(1024,620,1,'messages.php?id=<?php echo ($row['id'])?>')">View</button></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
               </tr>
               <?php
            }
     }
     else
     {
            ?>
            <tr>
            <td>Nothing here...</td>
```

Note:  This page has 'pagination (PDO)' which is all working fine --
and passes the correct "id" in the URL.

This is the page I am having trouble with:
( the entire page's code is shown here)

```
    <?php require_once ('connections/myDB.php'); 

    if (($sermonID = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))         !== false && $id > 0) {
// id was passed and it's a valid integer
    } else {
        // I have nothing here yet, recommendations appraciated)
        // evil request, die die
    }

    try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;charset=$charset", $db_name, $db_pass );

    foreach ($conn->query('Select * From messages ')as $row){
    $row['sermonID'];}

    } 

    catch (PDOException $pe) {
die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
    }
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head> 

    </head>
    <body>




     <video width="640" height="480" poster="images/myImage.jpg" controls="controls" preload="none">

     <source type="video/mp4" src='<?php echo $row['fName']; ?>' /></video>
     <p><?php echo $row['date']; ?></p>
     <p><?php echo $row['description'];?></p><br>

     <p>Video files are large. Depending on your connection, they may take a few moments to begin.</p> 

<p><button class="w3-btn w3-round-xxlarge w3-white" onClick="window.close()">Close Window</button>
    </body>
    </html>
    <script>
    function closeWindow()
    { 
    // Close the current window
    window.close();
    }
    </script>
```

As stated, the page loads just as it is supposed to, the correct "id" shows in the URL (myWebSite.com/messages.php?id=4 or ?id=5, 6 etc etc)

However, the video (and the misc info that goes with it) is always the very last entry in the database, never the number 1, 2 or 3 etc in the database.

Can someone please guide me in the right direction?  I'm sure it is something simple I am overlooking but I have been working on this problem for well over a week and I am fed up with myself and am at wits end.  I have tried foreach, while, for and everything else in between to no avail.

My stepson and I am very grateful for any help or for pointing me in the right direction.  I think I have given enough info (code) and have tried to be as clear as possible.  Please respond with any additional info needed.

Thanks.

Comment: You are closing foreach loop too early, leaving only last row to be displayed. Also, I'd strongly suggest you to read my [PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo), because you are using it completely wrong way.

Comment: @2-cents tim    Sorry for delay in getting back and Thanks for your suggestions (A storm came through and tried to knock the church down).  I tried the above but now I am getting a "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in....        Some add'l info that may make a difference:  host = godaddy, PHP version = 5.2.17 (will upgrade to 5.3 once I get this up and running).  mysql API and PDO vers. = 5.0.77.   Should I be using prepared Stmt and fetching the column like I read in YCS's tutorial?

Answer (score -2):

Tested it this time . . added WHERE clause to sql statement.

```
    function pdo_connect() {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    return $dbh;
    }


    $id = $_GET['id'];
if (($sermonID = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) !== false && $id > 0) {
    // id was passed and it's a valid integer
} else {
    // I have nothing here yet, recommendations appraciated)
    // evil request, die die
}

try {
    $conn = pdo_connect();

foreach ($conn->query("Select * From messages WHERE sermonID = $sermonID")as $row)
    {
$row['sermonID'];}

} 

catch (PDOException $pe) {
    die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 

</head>
<body>



        <!-- skip the video 
 <video width="640" height="480" poster="images/myImage.jpg" controls="controls" preload="none">

 <source type="video/mp4" src='<?php echo $row['fName']; ?>' /></video>
 <p><?php echo $row['date']; ?></p>
 <p><?php echo $row['description'];?></p><br>

     -->

     <p><?php echo $row['fName']; ?></p>
     <p><?php echo $row['description'];?></p>
 <p>Video files are large. Depending on your connection, they may take a few moments to begin.</p> 

    <p><button class="w3-btn w3-round-xxlarge w3-white" onClick="window.close()">Close Window</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, 2-cents tim.  I just tried both of your suggestions.  However, I am still getting the last entry in the database just as before.  The number of pages to show on each page was set to three but now it only shows the first entry in the database for page one, the second entry in database for page 2 and the third for page three.  So far I have nine pages in total ( 3 per page)